# How are the left inverses of an injection, surjective?

Tags: functions

Consider the injection $f:{{0,1,2}} \to {0,1,2,3}:x\to x $

Now consider the left inverse of this function. How exactly is this a surjection if not all the elements in the codomain are mapped back?

[image: Example]

Comment: This function has $3$ left inverses. Can you find them?

Comment: Ah so you're saying that there *exists* a surjective inverse?

Comment: No, I'm asking you to explicitly write down the left inverses. Implicitly yes, I'm saying it has.

Comment: I see. But my lecture notes say that *all* left inverses (of injective functions) are surjective. But the diagram in the post above could be a non surjective left inverse too no?

Comment: No, how it could have? Specify your concern. Are you sure you are thinking about a function $\{0,1,2,3\}\to\{0,1,2\}$?

Comment: if you want maps to be _total_, your diagram does not represent a left inverse.

Answer (score 0):

The given function $f$ has exactly 3 left inverses.

Note that a left inverse $g$ of $f$ must be a *function* $\{0,1,2,3\}\to\{0,1,2\}$ so that $g(f(x))=x$ for all $x\in\{0,1,2\}$.

So, we must have $g(0)=0,\ g(1)=1,\ g(2)=2$, and also $g(3)\in\{0,1,2\}$, which actually can be arbitrary.

Because of the equation $g(f(x))=x$ we see that indeed any such $g$ must be surjective, since for arbitrary $x$ in the codomain of $g$ (=domain of $f$) we have an element, specifically e.g. $f(x)$ which $g$ carries into $x$.